# Sending scapegoat reports into sonarqube

Tags: scala, sonarqube, code-analysis

My scapegoat generates reports into folders:

target/scapegoat/mainproject/project1/scapegoat-scalastyle.xml
target/scapegoat/mainproject/project2/scapegoat-scalastyle.xml

etc

I've added (according to this: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/external-issues/) to my properties in pom a line:

```
        <sonar.scala.scapegoat.reportPaths>
        ./target/scapegoat/mainproject/**/scapegoat-scalastyle.xml
    </sonar.scala.scapegoat.reportPaths>
```

apart from that, I of course have

```
<sonar.host.url>my url</sonar.host.url>
    <sonar.login>my login</sonar.login>
 <sonar.language>scala</sonar.language>
```

and on dependencies:

```
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.slang</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-scala-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0.883</version>
        </dependency>
```

After mvn sonar:sonar I don't see data in my sonarqube server. Could anyone help me?

Comment: I would recommend you to use [**sonar-scala**](https://sonar-scala.com/) instead of the official scala plugin, it has native support for **scapegoat**, **scalastyle** & **scoverage**. - Disclaimer: I worked on that projet.

Comment: Will it work with maven instead of sbt?

Comment: Yeah, in the end, both just call the `sonar-scanner` executable or they implement the scanner api. Whatever the case, it doesn't matter because who does the analysis is the plugin installed in the server.

Comment: But can I use it only for send results from scapegoat? I don't want to generate another report, just send scapegoat's.

Comment: I do not understand that question. **sonar-scala** is a server plugin, it doesn't care what you use to build your project and how you run the analysis. AFAIK the official scala server plugin doesn't support **scapegoat**, **sonar-scala** does support it.